# C# SELENIUM - Como ler elementos de uma web page por menção de palavra chave

Tags: c#, testes, selenium-webdriver, automatização

Estou criando um Bot que pesquise uma palavra no google e escreva em um arquivo txt todos os links encontrados na pesquisa

Atualmente estou tentado localizar na página de resultado da pesquisa uma palavra chave, armazeno os links que contem essa palavra chave em uma variável e gravo no txt:

```
 string mencoesDaPalavra =  Driver.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText("Palavra a pesquisar")).ToString();
```

Após "capturar" os links que contem a palavra estou tentando gravar no arquivo assim :

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("new.txt");
        file.Write(mencoesDaPalavra);
        file.Close();
```

**Minha tentativa nao obteve sucesso, a linha gravada no arquivo nao condiz com oq estou buscando.. como eu poderia fazer ?**

linha gravada no arquivo :

> new.txt =
>    "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]"

Comment: O método `FindElements` retorna um array de objetos (WebElement) e não uma string. Você precisa iterar nesse array pra pegar os links.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem o seu problema...

Jogue o resultado do seu findElements em uma collection e faça um for each nela.

Em cada item (a) da collection use o GetAttribute("href") para pegar o link

Vou fazer um jeito diferente de pegar os elementos, mas pode usar do seu jeito mesmo. Depois diz se deu certo, ou eu viajei. Rsrs

```
    var colEl = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//a")).Where(el => el.Text.contains(palavraPesquisa));

    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("new.txt");

    foreach (var link in colEl)
            {
                file.Write(link.GetAttribute("href"));
                file.Close();
            }
```